# My service not runing when shut down phone or restart and when close all app

Tags: android, service, background-service

I am using a service for every second to check my database and if time now equals time in database show notification but when reboot or shutdown or restart my phone service kill and not show notification this is my code :

Content of AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <receiver
                android:name=".service.BootCompleteReceiver"
                android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

<service
            android:name=".service.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Content of BootComplate Receiver class :

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);
```

and in MyService class write this code :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
return START_STICKY;
}
```

But this is not working. Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: "i use the service for every second to check my database": this is not a good design as it will drain the battery of the device quickly. Have a look at alarms instead.

Comment: time is sample for this problem i can change it please help to solve this problem

Comment: Is your uses-permission tag at the right place?

Comment: sorry it work in android version below 6 and in version above 6 not work